# Cannot be redirected to another page from jquery Mobile navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to develop a mobile app using jQuery mobile and I used navigation bar tab widget code in the official documentation.
My first issue is that when I click on a tab from the navigation bar displayed on the footer, it doesn't direct me to the page I want. When I debug using Chrome's console I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined     jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js:4347 
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 
n.extend.each        jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 
n.fn.n.each          jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js:4338 
base.rewrite         jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js:5070 
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 
n.extend.proxy.n.isFunction.f      jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 
n.Callbacks.j                      jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith             jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 
xjquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b
```

Here's my accueil.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Accueil</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css">
<link href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Casa Elections App</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h2 class="mc-text-center">Bienvenue!</h2>
        <p> <center>Bienvenue dans la page d'accueil de l'application CasaElections.</center><br>
            Cette application est destinée à être utilisée par les correspondants des bureaux de vote. Son objectif est d'identifier les électeurs et compter le nombre de votants d'une part, ainsi que d'envoyer les résultats de vote après l'opération du dépouillement.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo2" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="accueil.html">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="identificationElecteurs.html">Identification</a></li>
                <li><a href="resultatsScrutin.html">Résultats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

> P.S : when  I go to identificationElecteurs.html page and I click on the Accueil tab, I'm redirected to that page. Which is weird since I can't do the same going from the accueil.html to identificationElecteurs.html page nor from the resultatsScrutin.html page to identificationElecteurs.html.

The resultatsScrutin.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Authentification</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css">
<link href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Casa Elections App</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <!--Tabs navigation-->
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" >
          <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">BV</a></li>
              <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">PP</a></li>
              <!-- <li><a href="ajax-content-ignore.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li> -->
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            
        <!-- Will use the id to call on AJAX-->
        <form id="form1" data-ajax="false" method="post">
            <h3><center>Résultats après dépouillement</center></h3>

            <label for="txt-cin">N° de CIN</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt-cin" id="txt-cin" value="" placeholder="Taper votre nom d'utilisateur">

            <button class="ui-btn ui-mini">Rechercher</button>
        </form>

          </div>
          <div id="two">
            <form id="form2" data-ajax="false" method="post">
                <h3><center>Résultats après dépouillement</center></h3>

                <label for="txt-nbre-ve">Nombre de voix exprimées (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-ve" id="txt-nbre-ve" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 456">

                <label for="txt-nbre-bn">Nombre de bulletins nuls (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-bn" id="txt-nbre-bn" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 457">

                <label for="txt-nbre-insc">Nombre d'inscrits (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-insc" id="txt-nbre-insc" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 458">

                <label for="txt-nbre-votants">Nombre de votants (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-votants" id="txt-nbre-votants" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 459">

                <button class="ui-btn ui-mini">Valider</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo2" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="accueil.html">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="identificationElecteurs.html">Identification</a></li>
                <li><a href="resultatsScrutin.html">Résultats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't help you on all the matters mentioned above. Why don't you split them into different questions since the fields differ?

Comment: @DanielCheung because I figured they are related somehow to the jQuery mobile navbar widget !

Comment: @Regent I don't understand what u meant? What script did I include twice?

Comment: You include jQuery Mobile: `<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`, and then you include it once more:
`<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>`. I don't know whether it causes all kind of troubles, but it's definitely not good.

Comment: The first one's extension is ".min.js" and the other one is ".js".. They are two different files, aren't they?

Comment: They are different files but they have the **same** code. _min_ means that code is minified.

Comment: I see! And what's the difference between them? When should we use each one of them.. 'Cause I've seen them in many scripts being included both :/ Could u enlighten this point for me please ?

Comment: I deleted the link to the ".min.js" file and refreshed the page.. Still getting the same issues !

Comment: Not minified version is supposed to be used during development and debugging, while minified version is for production. Minified version has less size (in KB), so it is downloaded faster during page loading in client's browser. Less size with same functionality is achieved by removing spaces and`{}()` where it is possible, by shortening variables' names to 1-2 symbols and some more tricks.

Comment: Now it's clear! Thanks a lot @Regent for the clarification :) Now concerning my issues, what do u think is wrong with my code ?!

Comment: @DanielCheung I edited my question but I couldn't post the other one. I have to wait 90 min to do so :) So here I am waiting.. In the meanwhile, do u have some thoughts on my code and what could be wrong with it?

Comment: @GeoSal you're welcome. About your issue: I see _<a href="resultatsSc**ru**tin.html">_ in code and _resultatsSc**ur**tin.html_ in your question's text. Is it typo in link or in your question's text in SO?

Comment: It's actually resultatsScrutin.html.. It was a typo in my question's text in SO (thanks for the heads up btw !)

Comment: @GeoSal well, then unfortunately I have no other ideas what is wrong here. By the way, you can try to use "multiple pages in single file", even though it's not very good template, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: @Regent Thanks a loot though for ur answers.. Really appreciate it! I hope someone else could give me a hand on this.. BTW, here's the link to my other-related question after my post edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561420/tabs-from-navbar-not-well-diplayed-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed. Apparently it was just some JS conflict.