# Tabs from navbar not well diplayed : jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to develop a mobile app using jQuery mobile and I used navigation bar tab widget code in the official documentation.
My issue is related to the navbar as it is not displayed as it should be! The two tabs are not within the same line ! (Again, I used the code from the documentation and adjusted it only)..

[image: Screenshot of the displayed page]

The resultatsScurtin.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Authentification</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css">
<link href="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Casa Elections App</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <!--Tabs navigation-->
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" >
          <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">BV</a></li>
              <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">PP</a></li>
              <!-- <li><a href="ajax-content-ignore.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li> -->
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
            
        <!-- Will use the id to call on AJAX-->
        <form id="form1" data-ajax="false" method="post">
            <h3><center>Résultats après dépouillement</center></h3>

            <label for="txt-cin">N° de CIN</label>
            <input type="text" name="txt-cin" id="txt-cin" value="" placeholder="Taper votre nom d'utilisateur">

            <button class="ui-btn ui-mini">Rechercher</button>
        </form>

          </div>
          <div id="two">
            <form id="form2" data-ajax="false" method="post">
                <h3><center>Résultats après dépouillement</center></h3>

                <label for="txt-nbre-ve">Nombre de voix exprimées (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-ve" id="txt-nbre-ve" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 456">

                <label for="txt-nbre-bn">Nombre de bulletins nuls (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-bn" id="txt-nbre-bn" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 457">

                <label for="txt-nbre-insc">Nombre d'inscrits (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-insc" id="txt-nbre-insc" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 458">

                <label for="txt-nbre-votants">Nombre de votants (En chiffres) :</label>
                <input type="text" name="txt-nbre-votants" id="txt-nbre-votants" value="" placeholder="Exemple : 459">

                <button class="ui-btn ui-mini">Valider</button>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo2" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="accueil.html">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="identificationElecteurs.html">Identification</a></li>
                <li><a href="resultatsScrutin.html">Résultats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://i.imgur.com/gW6NYU3.png). Have you set some zoom on your page? Because I can't see it as large as your image (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: @Sga No I haven't set some zoom on the page.. I'm using actually Chrome's emulator and the device model I'm testing the code on is Samsung actually (Though I don't think it should be a problem, right? Isn't jQuery mobile conceived to be compatible with all the devices? ) BTW, I've tried Apple 6 same as u did, but still got the same problem...

Comment: I tried with all devices both on Chrome 41.0.2272.118 and Canary 44.0.2363.0... it works for me ?_?

Comment: This is really weird :( :(

Comment: Try moving to jQM 1.4.5, then test it on a real device...

Comment: I have tried jQM 1.4.5.. Same issue! And for the test on a real device, how do I do that? Don't I have to deploy the app first?

Comment: Fortunately, with a webapp you can just upload your HTML to a webserver then reach it with your device (even on a local network through WiFi)

Comment: I'm working on my own machine, can u please elaborate how is it possible to do that?

Comment: Another thing is that I actually would like once I'm done with the coding to deploy my application using Cordova or sth like it (if u have other alternatives I would really appreciate if u'd share them with me, the thing is I had a previous problem with Phonegap/Cordova's installation, and I had no choice but to switch to jQuery Mobile since I was running out of time.. u can check my asked questions)

Comment: [Use this](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) as a webserver. For deployment, jQM+PhoneGap seems the right choice

Comment: @Sga I just tried using Moongoose. I actually copied the directory of my project and edited the document_root setting to be : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CasaElectionsMobileApp But I had the page rendered with no style.. As if the css files and jquery mobile files were not recognized !!

Comment: With Chrome's console I get multiple lines linked to jquerymobile js and css files, something like : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: yep, you have to change your `src="../CasaElectionsMobileApp/` path references... or move Mongoose in your project root

Comment: Change it to what exactly? Can u be more specific please?

Comment: use absolute paths or fix your relative ones

Comment: What should I put as a directory in the document_root path? Cause what I did is giving the path mentioned above in my previous comment, the path where the project is hosted on my local machine with IIS as a server.. I can't find some directory like www or wwwroot for mongoose.. So what should I mention as a path ?

Comment: Here's what I get with that javascript error I mentionned http://192.168.215.1:8080/CasaElectionsMobileApp/public/jquery.mobile-1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css.. This along with the other files

Comment: you have IIS? Forget Mongoose, just access your server with your device!

Comment: I can't access it now with my device.. The page is not even loaded, I have : Inaccessible page

Comment: @Sga I disabling the firewall.. Still can't access the page from my device.. Any thoughts please ?

Comment: sorry but I can't solve the problem on your network. Simplify your environment.